# Where can I find Hindi translation of Gospel of Ramakrishna known as Ramakrishna Vachanamrita?

Tags: ramakrishna

It would be helpful if I can get pdf of the same. They are available online but I can't find all parts. Thanks!

Comment: Can you get all parts from this link?: https://www.kathamrita.org/kathamrita

Comment: @Rickross this orignal Kathamrita translation not RKM version of gospel. Either way, it's missing the first part for years now.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is the one that you are looking for:

https://archive.org/details/HindiBookShriRamKrishnaVachanamritBhag1/mode/2up

And this is the audio for the second Bhag (I couldn't find a pdf of it):

https://archive.org/details/09.SriRamkrishnaVachanamrita

Comment: Sadly that's all I could find too. Other bhags are missing. Only audio is available. Let's see if someone can link all parts.

Comment: @RishX Here is the pdf for the second part : https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.464203/mode/2up

Comment: i think i also saw third part somewhere. Do you know how many parts there? I assume 5.